# bounds for hypergeometric 2F2 function

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Looking for lower- and upper- bounds for the following case of the hypergeometric ${}_pF_q$ function:
$$
{}_2F_{2}(1,k;\;k+1/2+b,k+1/2-b;\;z),
$$
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $b\in[0,1/2)$, and $z\ge0$. Can anyone suggest a reference?